# changing logo position in responsive theme

Tags: theme, header

I'm using the ultimo theme, and have some issues with header logo position.

My logo is a square box, with some graphics 'sticking out' on the left. Let's say it looks like this:

http://goodlogo.com/images/logos/calvin_klein_logo_2623.gif

The K is the edge of the box, and the C is ‘sticking out’.

In the default layout, this alignment looks no so good – the logo is too far right. What I need is for the edge of the box (K), to be aligned with the left border of the page body/menu nav.

If I force the CSS like this:

> .header .logo-wrapper {       position: relative;
>       left: -15px; }

It kind of works, moving the logo a little to the left and the alignment looks as I’d hope.

But the responsiveness breaks. I need to somehow adjust the css  when the small sizes kick in.

How can I do that? What is the best way to move the logo left?

*(I know this might be theme specific - but not sure, so asking anyhow. I have a feeling this is more about responsive-theme handling in general)*

update: here's a graphic to show what I mean: [image: https://s29.postimg.org/ioh9v58kn/example.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach for large screens is correct, but I would suggest using negative margin instead of left positioning. Now, when the screen is smaller, your content container will ocupy all the width of the screen, so you cannot use a negative margin anymore because the logo will go outside the container, i.e. outside the screen.

In this case you will have to reset the left margin to 0 like this:

```
.header .logo-wrapper { margin-left: -15px; }
media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { // You can change the breakpoint to whatever you want
    .header .logo-wrapper { margin-left: 0px; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. In the end, the following worked nicely it seems:  
`media only screen and (min-width: 1280px)  {  
 .header .logo { margin-left: -15px; }  
}  
  
/* 1280px <= width 1279 and 1024*/  
  
media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1279px) {  
.header .logo { margin-left: -9px; }  
}  
`